# Scoreboard in AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, class

im still quite new to AS3 and it's learning, and i've been following this guide (http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-pinball-style-rolling-score-counter-class--active-3109)  to create a pinball score system so when the object is hit/clicked you gain points. The final copy will be when the ball hits, but for testing purposes, it just want to be able to click it and the points are awarded.

I currently have the source codes for the guide.

my score.as is fine but im not sure what the game.as does, as i know it's to do with the clicking of the bumper.

My Bumpers are currently in an array called bumpersArray, here's the code associated with them i have for my stage.

and in my library their name is: bumper_1000 and their as linkage is bumper1000
because they give 1000 points when hit.

```
var bumpersArray:Array = new Array();
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length] = new bumper1000();
stage.addChild(bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1]);
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 30;
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].y = 270;

bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length] = new bumper1000();
stage.addChild(bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1]);
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) + 15;
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].y = 220;

bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length] = new bumper1000();
stage.addChild(bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1]);
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].x = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - 70;
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].y = 220;

bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length] = new bumper1000();
stage.addChild(bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1]);
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].x = 40;
bumpersArray[bumpersArray.length - 1].y = 110;
```

The rest of the files have been taken directly from the guide above, i hope i have explained myself enough, if you need anymore information - please just ask.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: that's a nice idea, I think I might use it... ary[ary.length]=mc; Very clever. Easier than ary[0]=mc; But what's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your asking is how to add score whenever you click a bumper simply use:

```
for(var i=0;i<bumpersArray.length;i++){
    bumpersArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,add_score);
}
function add_score(e:MouseEvent){
    your_points+=1000;
}
```